# How would I copy the effects of Sugarcult with just an amp?

Tags: electric-guitar, effects, punk

I’m having trouble finding a dial setting on my amp for clarity and the best combination of effects for Sugarcult’s pop/punk effects. The amp I have is an old Vox amp, nothing special. It does not have numbers around the dials, so number settings won’t work. I will edit with the model when or if I find it.

Comment: It's going to be hard for us to answer this. First, we don't know the *exact* equipment you have, and we would have to know that to even begin to suggest anything. Second, we can't know how things sound to you, so we can't know what sounds you will like and what sounds you won't like. There is no "best" combination of effects. You just have to play around and experiment until you find a sound that you like. It may take several years.

Comment: Tentative vote that this could stay open, if we remove 'pedals' from the equation, as that definitely gets too broad. We're often asked 'how do I copy this sound' & maybe knowing where to even start may help. no-one can know when you need to stop, but maybe where to start…

Comment: DIY is a big part of punk culture, as is "play first ask questions later." Try stuff until you like it!

Comment: Meh. Sometimes I think we're a bit quick on the trigger to close.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ok suppose we answered this as a "how do I copy this sound?" question. We still need a reference sound to copy, and one is not included in the question. "Clarity" and "best combination … for punk/rock" are insufficient descriptors.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I’m not sure if you would be able to tell the effects on the song I’m trying to play, but Sugarcult is the band, it’s a pop/punk band, I believe it’s similar to Green Day and blink-182. You might be able to tell the effects they use in their songs if you listen to a few.

Comment: Ahhh… now you've added what band… the trouble with copying Sugarcult, or Green Day [they both use the same tricks] is that you're not trying to emulate one sound, but two. Everything is double-tracked. Best you're going to do is add a 20ms single delay, possibly thin the delay in EQ before it hits the amp, though it's never going to be the same. I'll also revise my start point up to 8 from 7, or swap to a higher-gain amp. Neither of those bands really has a punk sound at all, it's actually a punk attitude that gives them the vibe. The sound is much more modern rock than punk.

Comment: ↑ above comment added to answer

Answer (score 3):

No-one can tell you exactly what settings, most especially on an old amp. Amongst the reasons are…

- Amps vary in response to input. Change guitar, or change technique, you change the sound
- Amps 'sag' over time & become softer-sounding. People do think to change the valves every decade or two, but very few ever know that the capacitors also need changing.
- Vox amps, in particular, can be very soft when old. Some few were made with an extra 'top boost' & these are much more controllable.

The only real guidance anyone can give - especially if you're aiming for pop/punk - is imagine every dial goes from 0 at its minimum setting to 10 at its maximum; or alternatively think of it like a clock face. Then start with everything set at 7; that's about 2 o'clock as a clock face.
Work from there.

Just because it's a Vox doesn't mean you'll get a specific sound from it. Look at Vox's own ['hall of fame'](https://voxamps.com/en-gb/artist/) list - few of these artists sound alike, even though we're told they all use the same make of amp…

One other thing to note - & this is actually very important, though forgotten or ignored by most people.
Every favourite guitar sound you've ever heard has been the sound of a guitar amp/speaker combo **miked up** [then recorded].  Unless you are standing at the front of a small stage or in the rehearsal room with the guitarist whose sound you like, you have only ever heard it miked.

*One other thing to add*
Get the amp sound right first, then think about pedals. Pedals add to the amp sound, they don't replace it.

*Late edit after actual band to be emulated was added…*
Ahhh… now you've added what band… the trouble with copying Sugarcult, or Green Day [they both use the same tricks] is that you're not trying to emulate one sound, but two. Everything is double-tracked. Best you're going to do is add a 20ms single delay, possibly thin the delay in EQ before it hits the amp, though it's never going to be the same.
I'll also revise my amp start point up to 8 from 7, swap to a higher-gain amp, or put a simple fuzz in front, dialled back to quite gentle, just to brighten & compress a little.
Neither of those bands really has a punk sound at all, it's actually a punk attitude that gives them the vibe. The sound is much more modern rock than punk.

For a bit of added history - Hugh Cornwell [Stranglers] used a Vox, but Steve Jones [Sex Pistols] & Joe Strummer [Clash] both  used Fenders.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we need to know what pedals you could use. Then what guitar you have. Then what strings are on that guitar. Then which pickups are on it. Even how you use your pick! (like where along the strings you pluck, and how).

Even then what Vox amp it actually is!

But with all that information, there are so many variables, that it becomes impossible to help you more, as when you listen to your genre, you'll realise there's not just one sound that's used.

So, sorry, I hope I've explained in an 'answer' that there's actually no answer!